# Is it safe to "half free" a chunk of memory to shrink it?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory, free

I have been told that even if it were safe it's definitely bad practice. My question is, is it actually safe to do this, or is it down-right undefined behavior? Suppose I have allocated a 100 byte chunk of memory, but I want to shrink it to 50. Would it be safe to add 50 to the pointer and free it? Here is an example in code:

```
char *ptr = malloc(100);
//...
free(ptr+50);
//Presumably, since I freed the second half only, would that be equivalent to ptr = realloc(ptr, 50);?
```

Is this cross-platform/undefined behavior? Is it safe to use this method of shrinking memory?

Comment: As dbush already stated, this is 100% undefined behavior and can break your heap. If you want to know _why_ this doesn't work, i'd recommend to look at the source of some heap implementations. If you do that you'll see that many of them place a header just in front of the pointer returned by malloc, and free() relies on that header to do its thing (the blocks you allocate and the associated bookkeeping information are located in the same region of memory). Because of this, an out-of-bounds access might end up destroying the entire heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only pass to `free` a pointer that was returned from `malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc`.  Passing anything else is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Section 7.22.3.3p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the `free` function states:

> The `free` function  causes  the  space  pointed  to  by `ptr` to  be 
>   deallocated,  that  is,  made available for further allocation.  If
>   `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs.  **Otherwise, if the 
>   argument  does  not  match  a  pointer  earlier  returned  by  a 
>   memory  management function,  or  if  the  space  has  been 
>   deallocated  by  a  call  to `free` or `realloc`,  the behavior is
>   undefined.**

The proper thing to do here would be to allocate a fresh block of memory, use `memcpy` to copy the bytes over, and `free` the old block.

Comment: Are you sure it would be undefined behavior in this case?

Comment: Can call realloc() instead of manually reallocating. The allocator may be able to resize the existing allocation and avoid the copy.

Comment: Re "*The proper thing to do here would be to*", Or `memcpy`/`memmove` + `realloc`

Comment: @Jeff: you can use `realloc()` to try and shrink the block but `realloc()` may return a different address, even in this case do you must update your pointer accordingly and also handle the possibility for `realloc()` to fail and return `NULL`.

Comment: @chqrlie I was suggesting `realloc()` in lieu of the "proper thing to do" suggested at the end of this answer.